# variable not being read in sql where clause

Tags: php, mysql

I can't figure out why the $stylist variable below will not work in the WHERE clause. $stylist echos correctly from the $_POST. When I swap it out with the raw value it works perfectly. I've tried wrapping $stylist in single quotes, double quotes, curly braces and dots, but nothing works. I'm completely stymied. Would really appreciate any suggestions. Thank you.

```
<?php
if($_POST['stylist'] == "") {
$location3 =  get_permalink( get_page_by_path( 'error-stylist' ) );
header("Location: {$location3}");
exit;
}
else { 
$stylist = $_POST['stylist'];
echo "<br/>Stylist: <b>" .$stylist . "</b><br/>";
global $wpdb;
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_ctstylists WHERE stylist = '$stylist'";
$row = $wpdb->get_row($sql);
echo "Get row id: " .$row->id;
}
?>
```

Comment: If stylist is not empty and its a string than u need quotes

Comment: Some thing like "SELECT * FROM wp_ctstylists WHERE stylist = '$stylist'"

Comment: Thanks devpro, have already tried all those quote variations, but no go.

Comment: R u still searching ....??

Comment: Yes, still at it. I renamed all the names in database in case there might have been some sort of conflict, but still the same. I'm mystified

Comment: SELECT * FROM wp_ctstylists WHERE stylist = 'yourvalue' run this in phpmyadmin

Comment: Thanks devpro, when I run the statement in phpmyadmin with an actual 'value' it returns the correct row and highlights the 'value' correctly. In my code snippet above, the $stylist variable echos the correct value after taking it from $_POST['stylist'], but 2 lines later in the select statement it is returning a null value. BTW I have already amended that line and am wrapping stylist thus '$stylist'.

Comment: $sql = "SELECT * FROM ` wp_ctstylists ` WHERE ` stylist ` = '$stylist'"   ... use backticks around table name and column name... also use quotes around '$stylist'    (`) backtick

Comment: Thanks devpro, but unfortunately the backtics didn't make any diff. I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: what errors r u getting?

Comment: print_r($row);  after this line $row = $wpdb->get_row($sql);

Comment: also check $row = $wpdb->get_results($sql);

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution: '$stylist' with quotes in:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM wp_ctstylists WHERE stylist = '$stylist'";
```

But you should use prepared statements instead: [prepared statements in php](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)

Comment: Thanks Kurt,. I purposely stripped the select statement down to its barest to try to isolate the problem. I've already tried every quote variation, but no luck so far.